# The page property cannot be read when multiple PageViews error when resize browser

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

When I resize the browser, I got that error "The page property cannot be read when multiple PageViews are attached to the same PageController." I think that because a new `pageView` is created, So how can I solve this problem.

Note: The code below is a simplified sample.

Edit: when I remove this line `controller.aboutusPageController.hasClients? (controller.aboutusPageController.page ?? 0).ceil(): 0` the code work  normaly but I need it.

```dart
class AboutUs extends StatelessWidget {
  const AboutUs({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);
  final HomeController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenTypeLayout.builder(
      mobile: (context) => _Mobile(
        controller: controller,
      ),
      desktop: (context) => _Web(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Web extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Web({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);
  final HomeController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        MyCustomWidget(
            currentIndex: controller.aboutusPageController.hasClients
                ? (controller.aboutusPageController.page ?? 0).ceil()
                : 0),
        SizedBox(
          width: 370,
          height: 472,
          child: _ImagesView(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _Mobile extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Mobile({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);
  final HomeController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Column(
      children: [
        MyCustomWidget(
            currentIndex: controller.aboutusPageController.hasClients
                ? (controller.aboutusPageController.page ?? 0).ceil()
                : 0),
        SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 200,
          child: _ImagesView(
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _ImagesView extends StatelessWidget {
  _ImagesView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final HomeController controller;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      onPageChanged: (value) {
        // do something
      },
      controller: controller.aboutusPageController,
      itemCount: 2,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Image.asset(
        aboutContent[index].imagePath,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can simplify the widget without depending on outer data

Comment: it could be providing necessary data but minimal case. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)